# What is the best way to configure the position of a model / texture in xna project

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, mesh

I wanted to know if my method used below is the correct way to determine the position of my model before drawing on the screen.
Because when I want to create a floor duplicating my model. I find myself faced with the "Z-fighting" problem ^ ^.

thank you very much

Code sample to st position on my model before drawing :

```
model_Position.X = (float) 1.0;
model_Position.Z = (float) 3.0;
model_Position.Y = (float) 5.0;

// Draw the model. A model can have multiple meshes, so loop.
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model_ground_land1.Meshes)
{
    // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well 
    // as our camera and projection.
    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
    {
        effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
        effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index]  *
    Matrix.CreateRotationY(model_Rotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(model_Position);
        effect.View = View;
        effect.Projection = Projection;
    }
    // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
    mesh.Draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your method is correct for positioning the model. What comes to the Z fighting problem, it happens when two 3D faces are drawn in the same plane overlapping each other. As you say that you "duplicate your model" it sounds like this is the problem, not the model positioning itself. To resolve the fighting, you can set some nonzero value to `GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState.DepthBias` before drawing the second copy of the model. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.renderstate.depthbias%28v=XNAGameStudio.10%29.aspx):

> "Polygons with a high z-bias value appear in front of polygons with a
>   low value, without requiring sorting for drawing order. For example,
>   polygons with a value of 1 appear in front of polygons with a value of
>   0."